# .jar files wont open

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jar

When I double click on a .jar nothing happens. I was able to open them a week ago but now nothing.

Things I have tried so far:

- reinstalling both JRE and JDK
- Running jarfix.exe
- creating a .bat file

**.bat file**
When I create a .bat file and put it in the same folder or when I try to open the .jar using CMD - as Administrator I get the same error.

This is my .bat file:

```
java -jar -debug <File Name>.jar  
pause
```

And this is my error message:

(I'll provide 3 examples of 3 different .jar files)
**(1)**

```
F:\Games\RSPS\Tools\Displee>java -jar -debug "model_editor_1.4.1.jar"  
Error: Could not find or load main class etc.Main  
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application  

F:\Games\RSPS\Tools\Displee>pause  
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**(2)**

```
F:\Games\RSPS\Tools\RSPSi\RSPSi>java -jar -debug Editor.jar  
Error: Could not find or load main class com.rspsi.LauncherWindow  
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application  

F:\Games\RSPS\Tools\RSPSi\RSPSi>pause  
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**(3)**

```
F:\Games\RSPS\Tools>java -jar -debug bsp-3.0.4.jar  
Error: Could not find or load main class io.nshusa.App  
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application  

F:\Games\RSPS\Tools>pause  
Press any key to continue . . .
```

**CMD**
When I open CMD and type

```
java -version
```

I get this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -version  
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and when I type

```
ftype | find "jarfile"
```

I get this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ftype | find "jarfile"  
jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

It seems as if everything should be working properly but unfortunately it is not and I don't know where to go from here which is why I turned to all of you. I just want to remind you that

- all .jar files would open for me a week ago
- no .jar files will open now
- I have been using Eclipse and IntelliJ

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt6Si.png)

Comment: You **upgraded** Java. JavaFX is no longer included in most builds of the JDK. [Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/) includes it. Also, there isn't really a JRE anymore.

Comment: (1) Where is JavaFX installed? Were you previously using Java 8? (2) Is your program set up as a modular program, with a module-info file? If so, you will need to include the location of the javafx modules. I recommend using openjfx.io and consulting their documentation. Also, using Maven can help eliminate some headaches, making it easier to create a jar file that can run with the normal java -jar yourproject.jar command.

Comment: I tried using **Liberica** but I was still unable to open my .jar files, but downgrading my jdk did work. I also want to state that this isn't my project/program but a program made to act as a tool to help me with my project. I downgraded to **Java SE Development Kit 8u241**

Answer (score 1):

@PhilFreihofner and @ElliottFrisch are right.
the Java GUI of JavaFx is only included in Oracle JDK/JRE 8. After Java 8, programmers have to use the openjfx GUI library instead.